# Pandas gives an unordered csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What can I do to make this (1 Pic): [image]

look like this one with pandas (2 Pic): [image]

Here's the code I used to make the csv file in the 1 Picture

```
import pandas as pd
import os 

all_months_data = pd.DataFrame()
files = [file for file in os.listdir('Sales_Data/')]

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('Sales_Data/' + file)
    all_months_data = pd.concat([all_months_data, df])

all_months_data.to_csv('all_data.csv')
```

Comment: *Import* the CSV into Excel. Side note, Excel is terrible with CSVs.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like your issue is in how you are opening the file.  To do what you've asked directly, you could select all of Column A in Excel and then choose Data -> Text to Columns

Comment: @Cargo23 Yeah, that's it thank you! Steel face problems, seems like exel is not friendly with the csv file

Comment: @BigBen you're right, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured the problem and it was Exel itself that have read my csv file as a text.
I did this and it worked:

1. Open Excel
2. Go to 'Data' tab
3. Select 'From Text/CSV' and select the .CSV file you want to import.
4. Click 'Import' and you're done!